# How can I create Answer Inline Query with URL

Tags: php, bots, telegram

How can I create AnswerInlineQuery with URL? I can't find any more details for that query, all sample code is about Telegram SDK, I need to code like this (URL  post, not class)

I tried this:

```
$data = array();
$data['inline_query_id']= $inline_query_id;//sample : 1515027006022511114
$data['results']='[
  {
    "type": "article",
    "id": "001",
    "title": "UC Browser",
    "message_text": "Text of the first message",
    "parse_mode": "Markdown",
    "disable_web_page_preview": true,
    "url": "telegram.com",
    "hide_url": true,
    "description": "Optional. Short description of the result",
    "thumb_url": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/64/uc-browser-icon.png",
    "thumb_width": 64,
    "thumb_height": 64
  },
  {
    "type": "article",
    "id": "002",
    "title": "Bitcoin",
    "message_text": "*Text of the second message*",
    "parse_mode": "Markdown",
    "disable_web_page_preview": true,
    "url": "bitcoin.org",
    "hide_url": true,
    "description": "Short description of the result",
    "thumb_url": "http://www.coinwarz.com/content/images/bitcoin-64x64.png",
    "thumb_width": 64,
    "thumb_height": 64
  }
]';

$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/answerInlineQuery',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'params=' . json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But result is:

```
Result : {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID"}
```

and I tried this too:

```
 $mResult = '[
      {
        "type": "article",
        "id": "001",
        "title": "UC Browser",
        "message_text": "Text of the first message",
        "parse_mode": "Markdown",
        "disable_web_page_preview": true,
        "url": "telegram.com",
        "hide_url": true,
        "description": "Optional. Short description of the result",
        "thumb_url": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/64/uc-browser-icon.png",
        "thumb_width": 64,
        "thumb_height": 64
      },
      {
        "type": "article",
        "id": "002",
        "title": "Bitcoin",
        "message_text": "*Text of the second message*",
        "parse_mode": "Markdown",
        "disable_web_page_preview": true,
        "url": "bitcoin.org",
        "hide_url": true,
        "description": "Short description of the result",
        "thumb_url": "http://www.coinwarz.com/content/images/bitcoin-64x64.png",
        "thumb_width": 64,
        "thumb_height": 64
      }
    ]';
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . TOKEN . "/answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=" . $inline_query_id . "&results=" . json_encode($mResult);
file_get_contents($url);
```

and this returns:

```
Result : {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$mResult = [
    [
        "type" => "article",
        "id" => "first",
        "title" => "Hey",
        "input_message_content" => ["message_text" => "Hello World"],
        "parse_mode" => "Markdown",
    ]
];
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . TOKEN . "/answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id={$inline_query_id}&results=" . json_encode($mResult);
file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to the answer given above, a bit has changed in the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultarticle), there is no field called `message_text` it is now called `input_message_content`

So you can try this

```
$inlineResult = [
[
    "type" => "article",
    "id" => rand(1, 100), //this has to be unique for each response
    "title" => "TITLE",
    "input_message_content" => [
      "message_text" => "*Hello World*",
      "parse_mode" => "Markdown",
     ],
] ];


$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . TOKEN . "/answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id={$inline_query_id}&results=" . json_encode($inlineResult);
file_get_contents($url);
```